# CSS ribbon "menu" isn't working as desired

Tags: html, css

So I've created part of a ribbon menu I plan on using myself. So here is what it looks like so far:

**Before hover:**

[image: Before hover]

**On hover:**

[image: On hover]

Basically, I want it to show my social icon as well as being able to use my other banners when i add them in.

Here is the code that I am using so far:

```
<body>
    <ul class="social">
        <li class="ribbon" media="facebook"><a href="http://facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    </ul>

    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/c2f336433a.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
@import 'reset';
@import 'mixins';

ul.social {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    margin: -225px auto;
    list-style: none;
    right: 0;

    li.ribbon {
        float: right;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;
        width: 75px;
        height: 250px;

        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 5px;

        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;

        @include transition(all .2s ease-in-out);
        @include filter(drop-shadow(0 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)));

        span {
            line-height: 20px;
            font-size: 5em;
        }
    }
    li.ribbon:hover {
        margin-top: 70px;
        color: white;
    }
    li.ribbon:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%; left: 0;
        width: 0; height: 0;

        border-top: 25px solid blue;
        border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    }
    li.ribbon:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%; right: 0;
        width: 0; height: 0;

        border-top: 25px solid blue;
        border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    }

    li.ribbon[media="facebook"] {
        background: #3b5998;
        color: #1e2e4f;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }
    li.ribbon[media="facebook"]:before,
    li.ribbon[media="facebook"]:after {
        border-top-color: #3b5998;
    }
}
```

**Note that the reset is just an eric meyer reset and the mixins are just for transitions etc...**

Comment: Maybe its just me but what exactly is the problem that you need fixed?

Comment: @Harry "Basically, I want it to show my social icon as well as being able to use my other banners when i add them in."

Comment: Do you mean like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/npnf86nb/)?

Comment: @Harry yes! only a bit longer heh but that won't be hard to adjust I presume :)

Comment: Ok, I set a small `min-height` which can be increased. But few more questions before you use that approach - How many such icons would you be having? How will the structure (HTML) look like with multiple icons? Currently, if you have multiple `li` items then you'd get multiple such ribbons. I am not sure if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: @Harry Yeah, I'm looking for multiple ribbons ^^ and probably only like 3/4 icons at the most

Comment: And the reason why you weren't able to see your icon was because the height of the element was 250px with a original negative margin of 225px on the `ul`. On hover, you were changing the `margin-top` of the `li` to 70px but the fact is the `ul` is still having the negative margin, so the `li` is still around 155px above the viewport and thus you were seeing nothing.

Comment: The first one was better in my opinion :) I would gladly accept that as an answer bud

Comment: Yep. As I said previously if it wasn't understood

Comment: Ooppssy, looks like I didn't fully/properly read your comment. Sorry for that. Will post the original fiddle as an answer now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you weren't able to see the icon was because there was a negative margin of `225px` on the `ul`. On hover, only the `margin-top` of the `li` was being set to `70px` but the `ul` still has the negative margin, so the `li` is still around `155px` above the viewport. This means that the `a` which is not positioned (that is, has static positioning) and is near the top of the `li` is still not visible.

You can correct this by avoiding the `margin` on the `ul` and just moving the `li` around. I've used the `transform: translateY()` to move the `li` around because that is better for performance than using margins (which need repainting).

I have also added some extra properties like `text-align`, `line-height` etc  for a *better look*.

```css
ul.social {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 4;
  margin: 0px auto; /* modified */
  list-style: none;
  right: 0;
}
ul.social li.ribbon {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  width: 75px;
  height: 100px; /* modified */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center; /* added */
  line-height: 100px; /* added, equal to height */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  transform: translateY(-100%); /* added */
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
}
ul.social li.ribbon span {
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 5em;
}
ul.social li.ribbon:hover {
  transform: translateY(0%); /* added */
  /* margin-top: 70px; removed for better performance */
}
ul.social li.ribbon:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 25px solid blue;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
}
ul.social li.ribbon:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 25px solid blue;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
}
ul.social li.ribbon[media="facebook"] {
  background: #3b5998;
  color: #1e2e4f;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
ul.social li.ribbon[media="facebook"]:before,
ul.social li.ribbon[media="facebook"]:after {
  border-top-color: #3b5998;
}

/* added */
ul.social li.ribbon a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul class="social">
    <li class="ribbon" media="facebook"><a href="http://facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/c2f336433a.js"></script>
</body>
```